# Using knowledge of radial distribution functions, how is it possible to explain the different electron configurations of V3+ and Calcium

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, quantum-chemistry, atoms

I recognize that the 3d orbital decreases in energy to lower than the 4s once it becomes occupied (even if I don't completely understand why?!). However, how is the difference in electron configuration of Ca and V^3+ explained by the radial distribution functions? This is a question from a problem sheet at my University and I can't seem to find an answer relating to RDF's anywhere.

Comment: It would be helpful if you included everything you mention into your question, e.g. pictures of the radial distribution functions and the electron configurations of $\ce{Ca}$ and $\ce{V^{3+}}$. Furthermore [this tutorial](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/88/189) shows you how math and chemical formulae can be nicely formatted on this site.

Comment: Please see this question for a better phrased version of this one: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/18988/how-does-the-radial-distribution-function-of-vanadium-differ-from-that-of-calciu

Comment: Please don't double-post questions. Instead of posting another question with improved phrasing it would have been better if you edited this question of yours.

Comment: sorry but do you know the answer?

Comment: I'm desperate. I have two problem sheets in for Monday and a mountain of work ontop.