# Correct Electron Configuration of Ni-28

Tags: electronic-configuration, isotope

I have seen two electron configurations for $\ce{_{28}Ni}$ in my chemistry textbook:
$$[\ce{Ar}]~3d^8~4s^2$$
$$[\ce{Ar}]~3d^9~4s^1$$
Which of those is actually the correct one (in reality)? Why exactly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

NIST suggests [here](http://physics.nist.gov/PhysRefData/DFTdata/configuration.html) and [here](http://physics.nist.gov/PhysRefData/ASD/ionEnergy.html) (search for Ni) that $\mathrm{[Ar] (3d)^8 (4s)^2}$, specifically in the state $\mathrm{^3 F_4}$, is the fundamental electronic state for neutral nickel atoms in empty space. However, [as Wikipedia describes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nickel#Electron_configuration_dispute), if you don't specify the [term symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_symbol) for the configuration, then the average energy of all terms for the $\mathrm{[Ar] (3d)^9 (4s)^1}$ configuration is slightly lower than the average energy of all terms in the $\mathrm{[Ar] (3d)^8 (4s)^2}$ configuration.

Now, *why* one configuration has a lower energy than another is a much harder question to answer in close cases such as this, as it involves a precise quantitative analysis of electronic energies for every possible electronic configuration of a nickel atom (a multielectronic atom). The general idea is that even though, for $Z=28$, the configuration $\mathrm{[Ar] (3d)^8 (4s)^2}$ is higher in energy than $\mathrm{[Ar] (3d)^9 (4s)^1}$ if you look at the sum of occupied orbital energies, the latter case has more interelectronic repulsions, which causes its total energy to be slightly higher. A lot of information on this can be found in [this previous Chem.SE question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/18988/1499) and the several nested questions within.

Interestingly, the gas-phase fundamental configuration of the monocation $\ce{Ni^+}$ is $\mathrm{[Ar] (3d)^9}$, which further shows how nickel's electronic configuration is teetering on the boundary between the options.